# How can I test a class which contains imported async methods in it?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, testing, ecmascript-6, jestjs

This is my first time working with tests and I get the trick to test UI components. Now I am attempting to test a class which has some static methods in it. It contains parameters too.

See the class:

```
import UserInfoModel from '../models/UserInfo.model';
import ApiClient from './apiClient';
import ApiNormalizer from './apiNormalizer';
import Article from '../models/Article.model';
import Notification from '../models/Notification.model';
import Content from '../models/Link.model';

export interface ResponseData {
  [key: string]: any;
}

export default class ApiService {
  static makeApiCall(
    url: string,
    normalizeCallback: (d: ResponseData) => ResponseData | null,
    callback: (d: any) => any
  ) {
    return ApiClient.get(url)
      .then(res => {
        callback(normalizeCallback(res.data));
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.error(error);
      });
  }


  static getProfile(callback: (a: UserInfoModel) => void) {
    return ApiService.makeApiCall(`profile`, ApiNormalizer.normalizeProfile, callback);
  }
}
```

I already created a small test which is passing but I am not really sure about what I am doing.

```
// @ts-ignore
import moxios from 'moxios';
import axios from 'axios';
import { baseURL } from './apiClient';
import { dummyUserInfo } from './../models/UserInfo.model';

describe('apiService', () => {
  let axiosInstance: any;

  beforeEach(() => {
    axiosInstance = axios.create();
    moxios.install();
  });

  afterEach(() => {
    moxios.uninstall();
  });

  it('should perform get profile call', done => {
    moxios.stubRequest(`${baseURL.DEV}profile`, {
      status: 200,
      response: {
        _user: dummyUserInfo
      }
    });

    axiosInstance
      .get(`${baseURL.DEV}profile`)
      .then((res: any) => {
        expect(res.status).toEqual(200);
        expect(res.data._user).toEqual(dummyUserInfo);
      })
      .finally(done);
  });
});
```

I am using moxios to test the axios stuff -> https://github.com/axios/moxios

So which could be the proper way to test this class with its methods?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

#### Introduction

[Unit tests](https://books.google.com.ua/books/about/Unit_Test_Frameworks.html?id=WvFuyuc5ZAEC&redir_esc=y) are automated tests written and run by software developers to ensure that a section of an application meets its design and behaves as intended. As if we are talking about object-oriented programming, a unit is often an entire interface, such as a class, but could be an individual method.

The goal of unit testing is to isolate each part of the program and show that the individual parts are correct. So if we consider your `ApiService.makeApiCall` function:

```js
  static makeApiCall(
    url: string,
    normalizeCallback: (d: ResponseData) => ResponseData | null,
    callback: (d: any) => any
  ) {
    return ApiClient.get(url)
      .then((res: any) => {
        callback(normalizeCallback(res.data));
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.error(error);
      });
  }
```

we can see that it has one external resource calling `ApiClient.get` which should be [mocked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2665812/what-is-mocking). It's not entirely correct to mock the HTTP requests in this case because `ApiService` doesn't utilize them directly and in this case your unit becomes a bit more broad than it expected to be.

#### Mocking

Jest framework provides great mechanism of [mocking](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/es6-class-mocks) and example of Omair Nabiel is correct. However, I prefer to not only stub a function with a predefined data but additionally to check that stubbed function was called an expected number of times (so use a real nature of mocks). So the full mock example would look as follows:

```js
/**
* Importing `ApiClient` directly in order to reference it later
*/
import ApiClient from './apiClient'; 

/**
* Mocking `ApiClient` with some fake data provider
*/
const mockData = {};

jest.mock('./apiClient', function () {

  return {
    get: jest.fn((url: string) => {
      return Promise.resolve({data: mockData});
    })
  }
});
```

This allows to add additional assertions to your test example:

```js
it('should call api client method', () => {
  ApiService.makeApiCall('test url', (data) => data, (res) => res);
  /**
  * Checking `ApiClient.get` to be called desired number of times 
  * with correct arguments
  */
  expect(ApiClient.get).toBeCalledTimes(1);
  expect(ApiClient.get).toBeCalledWith('test url');  
});
```

#### Positive testing

So, as long as we figured out what and how to mock data let's find out what we should test. Good tests should cover [two situations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8162423/what-is-positive-test-and-negative-test-in-unit-testing): **Positive Testing** - testing the system by giving the valid data and **Negative Testing** - testing the system by giving the Invalid data. In my humble opinion the third branch should be added - **Boundary Testing** - Test which focus on the boundary or limit conditions of the software being tested. Please, refer to this [Glossary](http://www.aptest.com/glossary.html) if you are interested in other types of tests.

The positive test flow flow for `makeApiCall` method should call `normalizeCallback` and `callback` methods consequently and we can write this test as follows (however, there is more than one way to skin a cat):

```js
  it('should call callbacks consequently', (done) => {
    const firstCallback = jest.fn((data: any) => {
      return data;
    });
    const secondCallback = jest.fn((data: any) => {
      return data;
    });
    ApiService.makeApiCall('test url', firstCallback, secondCallback)
      .then(() => {
        expect(firstCallback).toBeCalledTimes(1);
        expect(firstCallback).toBeCalledWith(mockData);

        expect(secondCallback).toBeCalledTimes(1);
        expect(secondCallback).toBeCalledWith(firstCallback(mockData));
        done();
      });
  });
```

Please, pay attention to several things in this test:
- I'm using `done` callback to let jest know the test was finished because of asynchronous nature of this test
- I'm using `mockData` variable which the data that `ApiClient.get` is mocked this so I check that callback got correct value
- `mockData` and similar variables should start from `mock`. Otherwise Jest will not allow to out it out of mock [scope](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/es6-class-mocks#calling-jestmock-docs-en-jest-object-jestmockmodulename-factory-options-with-the-module-factory-parameter)

#### Negative testing

The negative way for test looks pretty similar. `ApiClient.get` method should throw and error and `ApiService` should handle it and put into a `console`. Additionaly I'm checking that none of callbacks was called.

```js
import ApiService from './api.service';

const mockError = {message: 'Smth Bad Happened'};

jest.mock('./apiClient', function () {

  return {
    get: jest.fn().mockImplementation((url: string) => {
      console.log('error result');
      return Promise.reject(mockError);
    })
  }
});

describe( 't1', () => {
  it('should handle error', (done) => {
    console.error = jest.fn();

    const firstCallback = jest.fn((data: any) => {
      return data;
    });
    const secondCallback = jest.fn((data: any) => {
      return data;
    });
    ApiService.makeApiCall('test url', firstCallback, secondCallback)
      .then(() => {
        expect(firstCallback).toBeCalledTimes(0);
        expect(secondCallback).toBeCalledTimes(0);
        expect(console.error).toBeCalledTimes(1);
        expect(console.error).toBeCalledWith(mockError);
        done();
      });
  });
});
```

#### Boundary testing

Boundary testing could be arguing in your case but as long as (according to your types definition `normalizeCallback: (d: ResponseData) => ResponseData | null`) first callback can return `null` it could be a good practice to check if is the successfully transferred to a second callback without any errors or exceptions. We can just rewrite our second test a bit:

```js
it('should call callbacks consequently', (done) => {
    const firstCallback = jest.fn((data: any) => {
      return null;
    });
    const secondCallback = jest.fn((data: any) => {
      return data;
    });
    ApiService.makeApiCall('test url', firstCallback, secondCallback)
      .then(() => {
        expect(firstCallback).toBeCalledTimes(1);
        expect(firstCallback).toBeCalledWith(mockData);
        expect(secondCallback).toBeCalledTimes(1);
        done();
      });
  });
```

#### Testing asynchronous code

Regarding testing asynchronous code you can read a comprehensive documentation [here](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/asynchronous.html). The main idea is when you have code that runs asynchronously, Jest needs to know when the code it is testing has completed, before it can move on to another test. Jest provides three ways how you can do this:

1. By means of a callback

   ```
   it('the data is peanut butter', done => {
     function callback(data) {
       expect(data).toBe('peanut butter');
       done();
     }

     fetchData(callback);
   });
   ```

   Jest will wait until the done callback is called before finishing the test. If `done()` is never called, the test will fail, which is what you want to happen.
2. By means of promises

   If your code uses promises, there is a simpler way to handle asynchronous tests. Just return a promise from your test, and Jest will wait for that promise to resolve. If the promise is rejected, the test will automatically fail.
3. `async/await` syntax

   You can use `async` and `await` in your tests. To write an async test, just use the `async` keyword in front of the function passed to test.

   ```
   it('the data is peanut butter', async () => {
   const data = await fetchData();
   expect(data).toBe('peanut butter');
   });
   ```

#### Example

Here you can find a ready to use example of your code
https://github.com/SergeyMell/jest-experiments
Please, let me know if something left unclear for you.

#### UPDATE (29.08.2019)

Regarding your question

> Hi, what can I do to mock ./apiClient for success and error in the same file?

According to the [documentation](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/manual-mocks#using-with-es-module-imports) Jest will automatically hoist `jest.mock` calls to the top of the module (before any imports). It seems that you can do `setMock` or `doMock` instead, however, there are [issues](https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/5584) with mocking this way that developers face from time to time. They can be overridden by using `require` instead of `import` and other hacks (see [this article](https://medium.com/trabe/mocking-different-values-for-the-same-module-using-jest-a7b8d358d78b)) however I don't like this way.

The correct way for me in this case is do split mock defining and implementation, so you state that this module will be mocked like this

```js
jest.mock('./apiClient', function () {
  return {
    get: jest.fn()
  }
});
```

But the implementation of the mocking function differs depending on scope of tests:

```js
describe('api service success flow', () => {

  beforeAll(() => {
    //@ts-ignore
    ApiClient.get.mockImplementation((url: string) => {
      return Promise.resolve({data: mockData});
    })
  });

  ...
});

describe('api service error flow', () => {

  beforeAll(() => {
    //@ts-ignore
    ApiClient.get.mockImplementation((url: string) => {
      console.log('error result');
      return Promise.reject(mockError);
    })
  });

  ...
});
```

This will allow you to store all the `api service` related flows in a single file which is what you expected as far as I understand.
I've updated my [github example](https://github.com/SergeyMell/jest-experiments) with `api.spec.ts` which implements all mentioned above. Please, take a look.

Comment: @Non, do you have any unanswered questions remaining? Our you need some additional detalization or explanations of some parts?

Comment: Hi, what can I do to mock `./apiClient` for success and error in the same file?

Comment: Hi @Non, I've updated my answer with this information together with my github example. See UPDATE (29.08.2019) section

Answer (score 5):

The unit test term is self-explanatory that you test a unit. A function in complete isolation. Any outside dependencies are mocked. Here if your'e testing makeApiCall function you'll have to stub it's parameters and then mock the ApiClient promise and expect the function to return whatever you're expecting it to return with respect to your mocked and stub parameters.

One thing that people normally forget and which is the most important is to test the negative cases of a function. What will happen if your function throws an error will it break the app. How your function behaves in case something fails. Tests are written to avoid breaking changes in the app.

here is a better guide how to test async functions in JEST which coding examples:

https://www.leighhalliday.com/mocking-axios-in-jest-testing-async-functions

Hope this helps

**UPDATE**

Mock your ApiClient

for pass case:

```
jest.mock('./apiClient', () => {
  get: jest.fn(() => Promise.resolve(data)) // for pass case
})
```

for fail case:

```
jest.mock('./apiClient', () => {
  get: jest.fn(() => Promise.reject(false)) // for fail case
})
```

now call your makeApiCall for both cases once for success and once for fail.

**for fail case:**

```
const makeCall = await makeApiCall( <your stub params here> )
expect(makeCall).toThrowError() // note here you can check whatever you have done to handle error. ToThrowError is not a built-in function but just for understanding
```

I've mostly done testing in Jasmine so this last piece of code is kind of a psuedo code.

Comment: Is there a way for you to provide the code to test what I need?

Answer (score 1):

I guess what you are asking is how to test `ApiService`. If this is the case, then mocking the very own thing you want to test would make the unit test pointless.

What I would expect is the following items

1. You just want to test logic in your own class, not in the library.
2. You don't want to make an actual network request, this spams the server and make the test slower to run.

If this is the case, then you should mock out some lib to control their behaviour and see how your class behave under those circumstances. And, mock out any operation that involves network IO, make your test faster and less reliant on external resources.

There are a few things you could check with some dependencies mocked out:

1. delegation, e.g. is `axios` called once, with the right param?
2. directly mock the behaviour of the lib, in your case using `maxios`.

```
import ApiService, { baseURL } from './apiClient';


describe('ApiService', () => {
  let axiosInstance: any;

  beforeEach(() => {
    axiosInstance = axios.create();
    moxios.install();
  });

  afterEach(() => {
    moxios.uninstall();
  });

  // usually 1 test suite for each method
  describe('#getProfile', (done) => {
    // mocking behaviour
    it('should perform get profile call', () => {
      moxios.stubRequest(`${baseURL.DEV}profile`, {
        status: 200,
        response: {
          _user: dummyUserInfo
        }
      });

      ApiService.getProfile((profile) => {
        expect(profile).toEqual(dummyUserInfo); // you get what i mean
        done();
      });
    });

    // directly mock axios
    it('delegates to axios', (done) => {
      // you should put this to the top to avoid confusion, it will be hoisted
      jest.mock('axios', () => ({
        create: jest.fn(() => ({
          get: jest.fn(() => Promise.resolve()),
        })),
      }));

      ApiService.getProfile((profile) => {
        // do some assertion
        expect(axiosInstance.get).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
        expect(axiosInstance.get).toHaveBeenCalledWith(url, someParam, youGetIt);
        done();
      });
    });

    // rmb to test some error case
    it('should throw when param is not correct', (done) => { ... });
  });
});
```